# Não consigo chamar um "id" do aquivo "MainActivity.kt" dentro do arquivo "activity_main.xml"

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

Olá. Estou iniciando na programacão.   Estou utilizando o Android Studio com a linguagem kotlin.

Estou tentando chamar um "id", que está dentro do arquivo "activity_main.xml" no arquivo "MainActivity.kt" , não estou conseguindo. Tentei importar o arquivo "activity_main.xml", mas também não consigo. Alguém já passou por isso, sabe como resolver ?

---

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

```
    principalTXT.setOnClickListemer {
        
    }

}
```

---

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/principalTXT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples de você obter a referência da sua View é:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val principalTXT = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.principalTXT)
        principalTXT.setOnClickListemer {
            // implemente sua ação aqui
        }
    }
}
```

Existe uma forma melhor de acessar essas referências chamada de "View binding", que eu recomendo no lugar de usar `findViewById`. Dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) se quiser ver mais detalhes sobre isso.